# Webpage encoding utf-8

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I am having massive problems and very confused of what to do?

**My Mysql database Collation**: latin1_swedish_ci

**My header**: meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

**Before something goes into the database I do a**: html_entity_decode($input, ENT_QUOTES);

**If I enter charachters 'åäö' into the database** and then display them, they show **Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶**

What can I do to take care of this? I don't understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).

Comment: Thanks, but even if I change the database collation to UTF-8 I have the same problem :(

Comment: You should try to repair the database; this can be done per table (even per column). _Old tables need to be converted._ Easiest per mysqldump maybe. And a nice encoding aware, editor like JEdit

Comment: I would rather suggest to use `utf8_general_ci` as Collation and also use `varbinary` for UTF-8 fields where you want to store `UNICODE` characters

Comment: Did you try `set names utf8` before inserting/getting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I changed from htmlentities() to htmlspecialchars() and everything is fine now.